# PHP DOM return as html

Tags: php, html, xml, dom

I have an xml file slider.xml with html code inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
    <title>Slider</title>
    <head>
        <script async="async" src='ws-custom/plugins/slider.js'></script>
        <script async="defer" src='ws-custom/plugins/functions.js'></script>
    </head>
    <footer>
        <script async="defer" src='ws-custom/plugins/jquery.js'></script>
    </footer>
</content>
```

In PHP I would like to:
1. load it (using simplexml, dom or other better solution) and store in a variable $xml;
2. create an array $head with both $xml->head->children();
3. return the original html code for $head[0] and $head[1].

I have tried using this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('slider.xml');
$head = $xml->head->children();
foreach($head as $element){
    echo $element->asXML();
}
```

but it returns self-closing tags:

```
<script async="async" src="ws-custom/plugins/slider.js"/>
<script async="defer" src="ws-custom/plugins/functions.js"/>
```

which is not valid html code for W3C http://validator.w3.org/nu/

I would like also to be able to write only async, i.e.
    
because it's valid html, but with simplexml it's not valid xml.

Thank you very much.
Best regards.

Comment: What's the purpose of `$xml = new DOMDocument();`? You're immediately overwriting the variable, so the first assignment is useless.

Answer (score 2):

I've edited the script, now it works perfectly.
Note please the row 6:
$element[] = null;

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml = simplexml_load_file('slider.xml');
$head = $xml->head->children();
foreach($head as $element){
    $element[] = null;
    echo $element->asXML().PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: What about converting $head (simplexml) in $head_dom using $anyDOMNode->ownerDocument or $head=new DOMDocument; $head->loadXML($xml->asXML()); They seem clean solutions, but I have not understood how to apply it.

Comment: @LorenzoDeTomasi

This is your solution:

<?php
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('slider.xml');
    $head = $xml->head->children();
    foreach($head as $element){
 $element[] = null;
        echo $element->asXML().PHP_EOL;
    }
?>

let me know

Comment: Perfect. Why  $element[] = null?

Comment: simplexml has not flag to decide if apply or not the self-closing tag, so PHP consider this https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#elemdecls and if you declare an element null or empty the self-closing tags will be not applied

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleXML` can't output the empty tags properly, you should use `DOMDocument` instead (LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG doesn't work in SimpleXML)...

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$xml->load("slider.xml");
$head = $xml->getElementsByTagName("head");
$headScripts= $head[0]->getElementsByTagName("script");
foreach($headScripts as $element){
    echo $xml->saveXML($element, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG).PHP_EOL;
}
```

This code gets a start point (the `<head>` tag), as you only want the first one it uses `[0]` and finds the `<script>` tags inside the start point.

Which with the test source gives...

```
<script async="async" src="ws-custom/plugins/slider.js"></script>
<script async="defer" src="ws-custom/plugins/functions.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. How to select only in the head tag, in case of scripts in more tags (i.e. footer)?

Comment: You can layer the `getElementsByTagName()` calls to get tags within tags.  I've updated the code to limit this, but the principle applies to other structures as well.

Comment: How can I get $head[0]->childElements (as simplexml->children())? I have found $head[0]->childNodes, but it returns also white spaces and tabs.

Comment: If you add `$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;` before you call `$xml->load()`, it will remove the extra whitespace and `childNodes()` will be OK.  IF you prefer to work with SimpleXML, you can do something like `$head2 = simplexml_import_dom($head[0]);` and then `$head2` is a SimpleXMLElement.